# Javascript for url redirection on save

Tags: javascript, radio-button, save

I was wondering what the code might be to have a form redirect you to a website when it is saved.

Java code on the form is:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
    function saveRadioButton(radioVal, hiddenId)
    {
        var hidden = document.getElementById(hiddenId);
        hidden.value = radioVal;
    }
</script>
```

Once saved I would like it to send you to x website....

Answer (score 1):

First Java != JavaScript.  Two different animals.

For JavaScript it's as simple as

```
window.location = "http://www.google.com/"
```

A simple Google search shows this...

http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascriptredirect.php

Comment: +1 for "Two different animals" XD. Just kidding, the answer is right and simple.

Comment: But wait, I think (based on the question) that it would be better to `form.submit()`

Comment: @JCOC611 You are right, assuming he wants to pass the parameters just assigned.

Comment: I thing it would be completely pointless to set them otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

So assuming you want to submit the value you've just set to `hidden`:

```
<form id="myForm" method="GET" act="http://google.com">
```

Assuming the id of your form is "myForm" and the hidden input element lies inside this form. In JS:

```
document.getElementById("myForm").submit();
```